# Assemble configuration file from "includes" during build process

Tags: json, build, cmake, yaml

I am starting a C++ project using CMake that will need to read from a configuration file (haven't decide which yet, was thinking of YAML because I find it more readable but could be JSON idk) that can get pretty big but should be easy to read.

So I think a good approach would be to maintain separated configuration files for each separated concern. I was wondering if there's any tool or library that can assemble these configurations in a single one which then I can serialize to an unreadable binary read by my application.

Being more specific I was thinking of something like this (in JSON syntax):

```
// File A
{
  "prop1": val1,
  "prop2": val2,
  "prop3": @annotationToFileB,
  @annotationToFileC
}
```

```
// File B
{
  "nestedProp3_Prop1": val3,
  "nestedProp3_Prop2": val4,
}
```

```
// File C
{
  "nonNestedProp": val5
}
```

Resulting in

```
// Assembled Conf
{
  "prop1": val1,
  "prop2": val2,
  "prop3": {
    "nestedProp3_Prop1": val3,
    "nestedProp3_Prop2": val4
  }
  "nonNestedProp": val5
}
```

Comment: What is the logic to determine that "nestedProp3_Prop1" should end up inside "prop3"? Try to avoid guessing based on naming, especially if the names/namefragments are not even letter-accurate identical.

Comment: @Yunnosch The annotation is placed as a value of "prop3".

Comment: I see, so its like an "include".